# GCP: How to delete project that is assigned to "No Organisation"

Tags: permissions, google-cloud-platform

I have been using Google cloud services for a few simple things over the years. Recently I've started to explore using GCP for learning about AI and I'm trying to get my projects in order.

For some historical reasons I appear to have a couple of projects that are assigned to "No Organization" and even though I have full admin rights on the G-Suite I don't seem to be able to get the permissions required to migrate them to the proper organisation nor delete them.

I don't even appear to be able to see the permissions or enable APIs required to change them.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of them?

Additional Information:

I'm the only person who has created projects associated with this g-suite domain. I did briefly create a second identity (since deleted) to work with projects; it is possible (though unlikely) that one of these two projects was created by that identity. The other project must have been created by my normal identity.

I can't tell whether I am currently the IAM Owner of the projects, I should be theoretically but I can't see the permissions. Everything I attempt to do with the projects complains about my not having the correct permissions.

"No organization" appears to be a state defined/created by Google.

Update 2:

If I go to the Google Cloud Platform Console and open the console left side menu, and click IAM & Admin for either of these projects it lists no owner/users and all the information is blank because I don't have permission.

If I try to go to project settings I'm told I don't have permission to view the settings and I would need to contact support (which I don't have permission to do).

I am Super Admin for all organizational units in my g-suite account.

[image: GCP Manage Resources]

Comment: Are you the IAM Owner of the projects? Are you using different identities for the project and the organization? Edit your question to ask one method (delete or move), include details on identities and permissions (IAM roles).

Answer (score 1):

To confirm who owns the project, go to the *Google Cloud Platform Console*, *open the console left side menu*, and *click IAM & Admin*. Ensure that a project is selected to see the project owner. **If you're not the project owner, you cannot shutdown the project.**

**To [move a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#assign_permissions) between organizations.**

> To move a project, you need the following roles on the project, its
> parent resource, and the destination resource:
>
> - Project IAM Admin (roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin) on the    project that you want to move
> - Project Mover (roles/resourcemanager.projectMover) on the project's    parent resource
> - If the destination resource is a folder: Project Mover    (roles/resourcemanager.projectMover) on the destination resource
> - If the destination resource is an organization: Project Creator    (roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator) on the destination resource

**[Migrating projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#migrating_projects_no_org) with no organization.**

> You can migrate a project that is not associated with an organization
> into an organization. However, you can't change it back to No
> organization using this process. If you have a project that is
> associated with your organization and you want to revert it to No
> organization, reach out to your Support representative for assistance.
>
> *Note: Reverting a project to No organization requires business justification.*
>
> The process of migrating a project not associated with an organization
> is similar to the process for migrating a project between
> organizations, but does not require all of the steps involved in the
> migration plan. To migrate a project into an organization, you should
> follow these steps:
>
> - Verify the impact on this project of the policies it will inherit.
> - Create a dedicated import folder in the destination organization, if    desired.
> - Assign Identity and Access Management permissions for the project and    the destination parent as detailed in Assign permissions.
> - Determine if you need to change the billing account.
>
> To migrate a project into an organization, run the following command:
>
> ```
> gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID \
>     --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
> ```
>
> Where:
>
> - **PROJECT_ID** is the ID of the project you wish to move into the organization.
> - **ORGANIZATION_ID** is the ID of the organization to which you wish to move the project.

You can review the full [guides and recommendations here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration).

**To review the [IAM permission](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/viewing-users-and-permissions) associated with the user account.**

> 1. In the GCP Console, open Cloud Source Repositories.
>
> Open Cloud Source Repositories.
>
> 2. Click the "All repositories" project selector and select the name of
>    the project.
>
> A page opens, displaying the repositories that belong to the project.
>
> 3. Click Settings.
>
> The General settings page opens.
>
> 4. Click Permissions.
>
> The Permissions page opens.
>
> From this page, you can view the following information about the users
> and accounts that can access the repository.
>
> **User information/Description**
>
> *Type Member*: Lists the member name and email.
>
> *Role*: Displays the role or roles that the account has for the repository.

**To delete[(Shutdown)](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects) a project:**

> You can shut down projects using the Cloud Console or the
> [projects.delete()](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/delete) method. A project must have a lifecycle state
> of ACTIVE to be shut down in this way.
>
> This method immediately marks a project to be deleted. A notification
> email will be sent to the user who initiated the delete operation and
> the Technical category contacts that are listed in Essential Contacts.
> A project that is marked for deletion is not usable. If the project
> has a billing account associated with it, that association is broken
> and isn't reinstated if the project delete operation is canceled.
> After approximately 30 days, the project is fully deleted. To stop
> this process during the 30-day period, see the steps to restore a
> project.
>
> or
>
> To delete a project, use the gcloud projects delete command:
>
> ```
> gcloud projects delete PROJECT_ID
> ```
>
> Where **PROJECT_ID** is the ID of the project you want to delete.

Comment: My organization doesn't have any other users of GCP apart from myself and I have full admin permissions for the organization. When I select either of the two projects in No Organization I can bring up the project dashboard but no users or other information are listed. If I go to the project settings I am told that 'Access Transparency is not available for projects that are not part of an organisation. To enable Access Transparency for a single project, please contact sales or support'.  The projects appear to have no owners or organization. So I can't do any of the above.

Comment: As far as I can tell no-one has permission to do anything to these projects other than get there name/id. It's baffling.